# Merge 2 Urls having common part

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url

I have 2 urls:

```
1. "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/XYZ/"
2. "/XYZ/Media/Default"
```

I want to combine both of them so that I get `"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/XYZ/Media/Default"`

How do I do this? Note that both the Urls are of type `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the two URLs based on separator `"/"` then merge the two lists without duplicates as following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var url1 = "C:/inetpub/wwwroot/XYZ/";
        var url2 = "/XYZ/Media/Default";
        var f = url1.Split(new[]{'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var s = url2.Split(new[]{'/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var fullurl = string.Join("/", f.Concat(s).Distinct());
        Console.WriteLine(fullurl);
    }
}
```

output:

```
C:/inetpub/wwwroot/XYZ/Media/Default
```

this solution will work on all cases even if intersection more then one dir

Comment: What if a nested folder has the same name as it's parent folder? Like `C:/Media/Media/File.txt`. The result will then be wrong I think.

Answer (score 1):

If they are always of the same form then you can do like

```
string url = string.Concat(url1.Trim(new[] {'/'}), url2);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with `System.IO` functions like `Path.Combine`?